# Fix point of a continuous function under some conditions

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis

Prove that under each of the following conditions the continuous function $f:[a,b]\to\Bbb{R}$ has a fix point:

1. $f([a,b])\subset [a,b]$
2. $f([a,b])\supset [a,b]$
3. When $f$ is bijective and ingective.

Comment: What have you done so far on this question?

Comment: Look up Brouwer's Fixed Point Theorem.

Comment: $f(x)=0$ has property 1. only if $a\le 0\le b$.

Comment: I did nothing because I don't know how to start!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

1. consider $g(x) = f(x) - x$ and compute $g(a), g(b)$.
2. consider $\alpha, \beta$ such as $f(\alpha) = a, 
   f(\beta) = b$. Try to apply 1.
3. if $f$ is surjective, just apply 2. ; if $f$ is injective,
   this is not true (consider $f(x) = x+1$)